# CSS and Bootstrap: Create a line that connects rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, bootstrap-4

So I have created three lows. Each row has two cols, one with text and another with an image:

[image]

The thing I want to create is a line that connects the pictures, highlighted red:
[image]

I don't have an idea how should I create this. I can export the line as a SVG or PNG, but I don't see how can I code it to work like in the picture.

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="container project-problemandsolution">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 project-problem order-lg-1 order-2">
        <h3>The problem and the solution</h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
        sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem <br> <br>
        onumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 project-solution order-lg-2 order-1">
          <img src="img/BubbleIllOne.svg" class="project-bubble" alt="Problem and Solution illustration">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container project-research">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 project-solution order-lg-1 order-1">
          <img src="img/BubbleIllTwo.svg" class="project-bubble" alt="Research illustration">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 project-research order-lg-2 order-2">
        <h3>Research</h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
        sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem <br> <br>
        onumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et

      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container project-lowfidelity">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 project-problem order-lg-1 order-2">
          <h3>Low fidelity design</h3>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, 
          sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem <br> <br>
          onumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
          At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 project-solution order-lg-2 order-1">
            <img src="img/BubbleTree.svg" class="project-bubble" alt="Low fidelity illustration">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
   .jumbotron {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.project-basic {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.project-basic-info {
    font-family: "Raleway Semibold";
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .project-solution {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .project-solution img {
        text-align: center;
        width: 330px;
        height: 250px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
    .project-solution {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .project-solution img {
        text-align: center;
        width: 260px;
        height: 220px;
    }
}

.project-problemandsolution {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.project-research {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.project-lowfidelity {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}


.project-buttons {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.project-bubble {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You can view the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/7uahbzgp/1/

P.S. The lines are not important for small screens. It just needs to show the connection on xl screens. So when you open jsfiidle, enlarge the screen to see it correctly. 
If you need the line as a svg: https://svgur.com/i/EbT.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only solution I found was **gorilla CSS**, where I added a new container with the image of the line:

```
<div class="container project-line">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="img/lineone.svg" alt="line">
  </div>
</div>
```

Since there are two lines, another one:

```
<div class="container project-line-two">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="img/linetwo.svg" alt="line">
  </div>
</div>
```

And then in the CSS:

```
.project-line {
    padding-left: 450px;
    margin-top: -64px;
    margin-bottom:-33px;
    z-index: -10;
}

.project-line-two {
    margin-top: -107px;
    padding-left: 201px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .project-line {
        display: none;
    }
    .project-line-two {
        display: none;
    }
}
```